# "Connection reset by peer" when getting sshfs to mount?

Tags: sshfs

I am trying to mount a remote directory using sshfs, but I'm getting the connection reset by peer error:

[image]

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Have you added the user pi to the www-data group?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the user pi to the www-data group?

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data  pi
```